# Equation of a straight line passing through passing through a point and equally inclined to two other lines

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

> Find the equation of the straight line passing through the point $(4,5)$ and equally inclined to the lines $3x= 4y+7$ and $5y=12x+6$.

I know that the equation of the bisector is given by:
$\dfrac{a_1x+b_1y+c_1}{\sqrt{a_1^2+b_1^2}}$=$\pm$$\dfrac{a_2x+b_2y+c_2}{\sqrt{a_2^2+b_2^2}}$

but I am facing real difficulty in finding which sign I should choose and why?

the answers are: $9x-7y=1 $ and $7x+9y=73$

[Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/d2bucjzz9g) is a Desmos graph of the above equation.

Comment: I don't understand: "equally inclined to the lines".

Comment: @GuillemusCallelus the angle bisector of two lines is equally inclined to the two lines

Comment: Choose the one which passes through $(4,5)$

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2440168/265466), albeit with specific lines and points. If you didn’t really understand the answer that you got, why did you accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using your idea we can get two slops: $m=\frac{9}{7}$ or $m=-\frac{7}{9}$ and from here two equations:
$$y-5=\frac{9}{7}(x-4)$$ 
$$y-5=-\frac{7}{9}(x-4)$$

Comment: Which "idea"of mine  are you referring two?

Comment: @Abcd I mean the following your idea: $\dfrac{a_1x+b_1y+c_1}{\sqrt{a_1^2+b_1^2}}=\pm$$\dfrac{a_2x+b_2y+c_2}{\sqrt{a_2^2+b_2^2}}$

Comment: Please verify : $\dfrac{3x-4y-7}{5}= \pm \dfrac{12x-5y+6}{13}$

Comment: @Abcd It's exactly!

Comment: But I got slope = $-7/9$ using this.

Comment: @Abcd Because it was my mistake. Sorry! I fixed. They are must be perpendiculars, of course.

Answer (score 0):

the straight line which passes through $$P(4;5)$$ has the equation
$$y=m(x-4)+5$$ converting the others into the Hessian Normalform we get
$$0=\frac{4y-3x+7}{\pm5}$$ and the other
$$0=\frac{5y-12x-6}{\pm 13}$$ the $$Point (0; -4m+5)$$ is situated on our line and we must compute
$$\frac{|5(-4m+5)-6|}{13}=\frac{|4(-3m+5)+7|}{5}$$
fromk here you will get $m$

Answer (score 0):

You have TWO lines which form equal angles with the given straight lines

$3x-4y-7=0;\;12x-5y+6=0$

$\dfrac{3x-4y-7}{\sqrt{3^2+4^2}}=\pm\dfrac{12x-5y+6}{\sqrt{12^2+5^2}}$

$\dfrac{3x-4y-7}{5}=\pm\dfrac{12x-5y+6}{13}$

$13(3x-4y-7)=\pm 5(12x-5y+6)$

$99 x-77 y-61=0;\;21 x+27 y+121=0$

$y=\dfrac{9 x}{7}-\dfrac{61}{77};\;y=-\dfrac{7 x}{9}-\dfrac{121}{27}$

If the wanted lines gave to pass through the point $(4,5)$ then their equation is

$y-5=m(x-4)$

where $m_1=\dfrac{9}{7};\;m_2=-\dfrac{7}{9}$

Hope this helps