# what is the gradient intuition in 2-dimention?

Tags: derivatives, vector-analysis

Hi

I've searched Gradient is like derivative but just in high dimensions 
now referring to dimensions of gradient,it says gradient is a vector that is perpendicular to function curve. consider function $f$ in 2-dimension if $f(x)= x^2$ then $f'(x) = 2x$ and it means the slope of tangent line in $x$ so now if we want to interpret it by gradient what can we say ? 
or for finding local minimum or maximum we use $f'(x) = 0 $ but in higher dimensions we use $\nabla f = 0$ and in 2-dimension  it's very easy to see $f'(x)=0$  get you local min/max but i can't interpret $\nabla f = 0$ Geometrically as a perpendicular vector for getting the local min/max of $f$ in n-dimension or even in 2 dimention.

I would appreciate for getting simple intuition about it.

Comment: The geometric interpretation of the gradient of a function depends on whether you’re looking at a surface defined explicitly by something like $z=f(x,y)$ or implicitly by something like $F(x,y,z)=0$. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2459214/265466) for more.

Answer (score 2):

I like to phrase it in a different way. I like to say that

`the gradient is the vector that points in the direction of bigger growth of the function`

In one dimension, the gradient (which is just the usual derivative) is either positive or negative. If it is positive, it means that if you are at $x $, then going right will make the value of the function increase. If the derivative is negative and you go left of $x $, the value of the function increases.

Say $f $ is a function of $x,y: f(x,y) $. If the derivative is $(0,1) $ in some point, it means that if you want to increase the value of the function as much as you can, you should go along the $y $-axis and up.

One verifies that this idea is the same as saying that the gradient is perpendicular to the level curves of a function. This doesn't make much sense if $f $ only depends on a single variable. But if you take $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$ then the level curves are circumferences centered at $(0,0) $ and the gradient is always perpendicular to them: radial direction and pointing outwards.

Of course these interpretations are only true for a neighbourhood of the point in question, but I find them rather explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

The gradient at a given point is perpendicular to the level surface of the function. A *level surface*, or isosurface, is the set of all points a function has a given value. For example for given function $f:R^2 \rightarrow R$ where $f(x,y) = x^2 -y$ the level surface corresponding to zero includes all points such as $(0,0), (1,1), (2,4) , \dots$. This level set of function $f$ is match with the curve of the function $g: R \rightarrow R$ where $g(x)=x^2$. At the given point (1,1), the line 
$$y= g'(1)(x-1) + 1 = 2x -1 $$ is the tangenet line to this curve. Note that $\nabla f = (2x,-1)$. You can obeser easily that $\nabla f\vert_{(1,1)} = (2,-1)$ is perpendicualr to the tangenet line $y = 2x-1$.

Comment: thank you for reply :)
but if we want find min of $f(x,y) = 0$ then we find $\nabla f =0$ for $x$-axis therefore level curves are just on $x$-axis
such as on $x=1$ the gradient on $x$-axis is $\nabla f =2$  and how this vector($\nabla f(1) =2$) is perpendicular to level curves on the $x$-axis?