# What is the proper equation to use when finding the tangent plane?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, 3d

My professor has introduced us to this equation when finding a tangent plane.

$$ z= f(x,y) + [\frac{∂f}{∂x}(x_0,y_0,z_0)] (x-x_0) + [\frac{∂f}{∂y}(x_0,y_0,z_0)] (y-y_0) $$

I am asked to find the tangent plane of the function $ f(x,y,z)= \frac{xyz}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$. I get the answer $z=y$ when I solve it myself, but I saw other solutions which used the formula $$ 0 = [\frac{∂f}{∂x}(x_0,y_0,z_0)] (x-x_0) + [\frac{∂f}{∂y}(x_0,y_0,z_0)] (y-y_0)+[\frac{∂f}{∂z}(x_0,y_0,z_0)] (z-z_0) $$
I am not sure which one to use, because this solution gives me $ y=0 $. Can anybody help clear up the difference between these two equations?

Comment: Definitely the second one is the correct tangent plane. In the first case you have written f(x,y). What does that mean ? Because indeed f is a function on 3 variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be confusing implicit and explicit functions. The second example function that you’ve given is a function from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R$, so its graph doesn’t have a tangent plane, but rather a tangent *hyperplane*, which you can find by extending your first formula by one more dimension.

I suspect that what you are really asking about with that second function is a surface in $\mathbb R^3$ that’s given *implicitly* by the equation $f(x,y,z)=c$ for some constant $c$. Such a surface is known as a *level surface* of $f$. That’s a different matter. If you can solve that equation for $z$ explicitly, i.e., describe the surface as the graph of a function of *two* variables, then your first formula applies. However, in many cases including this one that’s not possible, so you have to use a related, but different method.

There’s a theorem that says the gradient of a function at a point is always normal to its level surface at that point. The gradient is also orthogonal to the tangent plane (if it exists), so using the point-normal form of the equation of a plane, an equation for the tangent plane at a point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ on that surface is $$(x-x_0){\partial f\over\partial x}(x_0,y_0,z_0)+(y-y_0){\partial f\over\partial y}(x_0,y_0,z_0)+(z-z_0){\partial f\over\partial z}(x_0,y_0,z_0)=0.\tag{*}$$ The two formulas are related: If you have $z=f(x,y)$, then let $g(x,y,z)=f(x,y)-z$. It should be clear that the graph of $f$ is identical to the level surface $g(x,y,z)=0$. By the chain rule we then have for the gradient $\nabla g = \left({\partial f\over\partial x},{\partial f\over\partial y},-1\right)$ and if you plug this into (*) and rearrange you’ll end up with your first formula.

Comment: @dc3rd Check the edit log. The upvote brought this post to my attention and I spotted a minor typo that I’d missed before. There are no substantive changes to the content.

Comment: So I have a question. From this explanation what I gather tis that there are two distinct ways we are characterizing our surface. 1) we can explicitly write it out as a level set: $F(x,y,z) = c$ and 2) if we cannot write it out as a level set we can write it as $z = f(x,y)$? Then taking the gradient at a specific point we can write out an equation of the tangent plane? I read it another question , but still didn't completely get it, what is the difference between the two characterizations in how we use them?

Comment: @dc3rd It’s the other way around: you can always write $z=f(x,y)$ as a level set, namely $f(x,y)-z=0$. On the other hand, for the level set $F(x,y,z)=0$ of an arbitrary function $F(x,y,z)$, you generally can’t _globally_ solve for one variable in terms of the others (the Implicit Function theorem tells you when you can do this _locally_). You might also want to have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1912660/265466, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2459214/265466 and related questions for the geometric interpretations of $\nabla f$ and $\nabla F$.

Comment: Ah yes. So to try and extend what you're saying...IF I do have a characterization in the form $F(x,y,z) = c$, the gradient of this would help in expressing a tangent plane *globally*?

Comment: @dc3rd As to when to use one representation vs. another, it really depends on context. Even in $\mathbb R^2$, $y=mx+b$ is a convenient way to represent a line, but there are lines that can’t be represented this way; the implicit representation $ax+by+c=0$, on the other hand, can. The level sets of $x^2+y^2$ are circles, but but you can only represent a semicircle in $y=f(x)$ form, and so on.

Comment: Got it...Thanks for your time

Comment: @dc3rd I wouldn’t put it quite that way, but yes—you can use $\nabla F$ to find the tangent plane to a level surface of $F$ anywhere that $F$ is differentiable.