# How do you prove that angle bisectors are perpendicular to each other given two intersecting lines and their direction vectors?

Tags: vectors, bisection

> Prove that if two lines intersect and have direction vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$, their angle bisectors are always perpendicular to each other.

I know that if two vectors are perpendicular to each other they have a scalar product of 0.  Would I have to then show that ($\vec a\ + \vec b$)⋅($\vec a\ - \vec b$) = 0 via parallelogram?

Comment: I think you are on the right track

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is important that you first normalize vectors $\vec{OA} \, ( = \vec{a})$ and $\vec{OB} \, ( = \vec{b})$. Please see the below diagram as an example. The directional vector of angle bisector is in direction $OE$ but if you do not normalize the vectors, you will get a vector in direction $OF$.

[image]

So, $\vec{OE} = \vec{OC} + \vec{OD}$

Unit vector $\vec{OC} = \displaystyle \frac{\vec{a}}{||a||}$
Unit vector $\vec{OD} = \displaystyle \frac{\vec{b}}{||b||}$

So, $\vec{OE} = \displaystyle \frac{\vec{a}}{||a||} + \frac{\vec{b}}{||b||}$

Directional vector for one of the angle bisectors = $\lambda_1 (||b|| \, \vec{a} + ||a|| \, \vec{b})$

Similarly the directional vector of the other angle bisector = $ \lambda_2 (||a|| \, \vec{b} - ||b|| \, \vec{a})$

Dot product of both angle bisectors = $\lambda_1 \lambda_2 \, (||b|| \, \vec{a} + ||a|| \, \vec{b}) \cdot (||a|| \, \vec{b} - ||b|| \, \vec{a}) = 0$
(as $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{a} = ||a||^2 \,$ and $ \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} = \vec{b} \cdot \vec{a}$)

Comment: Thank you for explaining so thoroughly!

Comment: @nhoroz you are welcome.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2440168/equation-of-the-bisector-of-the-angle-between-two-lines-containing-the-given-poi/4237812#4237812. Nice answer.